# Fix Type of expression is ambiguous without more context Amplify Model

Tags: swiftui, aws-amplify

So I'm trying to save my form into a model, but i keep getting error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context", I've tried with just a simple model with 2 properties and have no problem. So I'm stuck and not sure how to move forward, haven't found anything helpful on internet.

````
        let me = Trip(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "Test", description: "Test", total: "0.00", coverImage: "lion", phase: Phase.new.rawValue, startDate: Date(), endDate: Date(), tenative: false, gallery: [], members: [], maxSeats: 50, paymentPlan: false) < -- this where i get the error

        //print(text)
        //        let trip = Trip(body: text)
        //        Amplify.DataStore.save(trip) { result in
        //            switch result {
        //            case .success:
        //                print("saved trip")
        //            case .failure(let error):
        //                print(error)
        //            }
        //
        //        }
        //        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        
    } ```

``` public struct Trip: Model {
  public let id: String
  public var name: String
  public var description: String
  public var total: String?
  public var coverImage: String
  public var phase: Phase?
  public var startDate: Temporal.DateTime
  public var endDate: Temporal.DateTime
  public var tenative: Bool
  public var gallery: [String]?
  public var members: [String]?
  public var maxSeats: Int?
  public var paymentPlan: Bool?
  
  public init(id: String = UUID().uuidString,
      name: String,
      description: String,
      total: String? = nil,
      coverImage: String,
      phase: Phase? = nil,
      startDate: Temporal.DateTime,
      endDate: Temporal.DateTime,
      tenative: Bool,
      gallery: [String]? = [],
      members: [String]? = [],
      maxSeats: Int? = nil,
      paymentPlan: Bool? = nil) {
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
      self.description = description
      self.total = total
      self.coverImage = coverImage
      self.phase = phase
      self.startDate = startDate
      self.endDate = endDate
      self.tenative = tenative
      self.gallery = gallery
      self.members = members
      self.maxSeats = maxSeats
      self.paymentPlan = paymentPlan
  }
}
````

Answer (score 0):

I actually is working now, I just recreated the model and tried again and error went away.